# Gulp uglify fails with js parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm strugling over a very annoying error. First at all: I'm new to gulp.

I try to realise a single page application with Angular. To make my workflow better, I tried to implement gulp.

I was heading some serious npm errors while installing some gulp plugins, but this is another story and i realised, that it's working with or without errors.

What I'm actualy hit my head on is the useref plugin. Or more exact, the uglify plugin.

This is in my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('useref', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

An this is the stacktrace it throws when trying to run it. 
C:\Work\evori-portfolio>gulp useref

```
[16:32:40] Using gulpfile C:\Work\evori-portfolio\gulpfile.js
[16:32:40] Starting 'useref'...

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2025:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2033:9)
    at expect_token (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2046:9)
    at expect (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2049:36)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2602:13)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2072:24)
    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2532:35)
    at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2708:19)
```

This stacktraces says absolutely nothing to me.

I watched at all of the destinations listed in the stacktrace and didn't found any failure.

I thought it could be caused by asynchrounus work that gulp does. Probably the uglify plugin tries to uglify the at this moment not finished useref file. How knows?

So I seperatet everything to be sure the error is not caused by overlapping plugins.

This is how i went through to reproduce the error:
1. gulp clean:dist

```
gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
  return del.sync('dist')
});
```

2. gulp useref

   `gulp.task('useref', function() {
     return gulp.src('app/*.html')
       .pipe(useref())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
   });`
3. gulp minify

   `gulp.task('minify', function() {
     return gulp.src('dist/**/*.js')
       /*.pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))*/
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
   });`
4. going crazy about the stack trace

   `C:\Work\evori-portfolio>gulp minify
   [11:55:50] Using gulpfile C:\Work\evori-portfolio\gulpfile.js
   [11:55:50] Starting 'minify'...`

   `events.js:141
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         ^
    Error
       at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)
       at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)
       at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2025:9)
       at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2033:9)
       at expect_token (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2046:9)
       at expect (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2049:36)
       at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2602:13)
       at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2072:24)
       at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2532:35)
       at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2708:19)
       at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2743:24)
       at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2748:20)
       at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2772:20)
       at expression (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2791:20)
       at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2173:39)
       at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2072:24)
       at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Work\evori-portfolio\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2352:20)`

**EDIT** OK... I've got in my index.html file a huge load of .js-Files. I tried to get that file, that causes the error by removing each and try to run useref+minify. And I got it. The bad file. When it is removed from index.html, minify works like a charm. But I have no idea, what I'm doing wrong or could cause an error.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('previewApp')
  .factory('dienstleisterRegObjService', function() {

    /* Aktuell ausgewähltes Produkt */
    var vorselektiertesProdukt = {
      servicetyp: '',
      dienstleistungstyp: '',
      produkt: ''
    };

    /* Registrations Objekt; wird per API an Server übergeben */
    var regObj = {
      organisation: '',
      vorname: '',
      nachname: '',
      mail: '',
      nationalitaet: 'Schweiz',
      sprache: 'Deutsch',
      produkte: []
    };

    /* Reset Methods */
    var getNewVorSelektProd = function() {
      vorselektiertesProdukt.servicetyp = '';
      vorselektiertesProdukt.dienstleistungstyp = '';
      vorselektiertesProdukt.produkt = '';
    };

    var getNewRegObj = function() {
      regObj.organisation = '';
      regObj.vorname = '';
      regObj.nachname = '';
      regObj.mail = '';
      regObj.nationalitaet = 'Schweiz';
      regObj.sprache = 'Deutsch';
      regObj.produkte = [];
    };

    /* Service Objekt */
    return {
      vorselektiertesProdukt,
      regObj,
      addProduct: function(servicetyp, dienstleistungstyp, produktparam) {
          var produkt = {};
          produkt.servicetyp = servicetyp;
          produkt.dienstleistungstyp = dienstleistungstyp;
          produkt.produkt = produktparam;
          regObj.produkte.push(produkt);
      },
      deleteProduct: function(produkt) {
        var index = regObj.produkte.indexOf(produkt);
        regObj.produkte.splice(index, 1);
      },
      resetVorSelektProd: function() {
        getNewVorSelektProd();
      },
      resetRegObj: function() {
        getNewRegObj();
      },
      resetAllObj: function() {
        getNewVorSelektProd();
        getNewRegObj();
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: I don't know why the formatting sucks.

Comment: ulp.task('useref', function() { . Check the spelling of "gulp" in this line you shared.

Comment: That's just a copy&paste fail. It's correct in my gulpfile.js. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know if there is a bug with some ES6 features, but try to put in your return statement `vorselektiertesProdukt:vorselektiertesProdukt` and `regObj:regObj` instead of just `vorselektiertesProdukt` and `regObj`

Comment: Thanks alot Zakaria. I already found it, but if you like these reputations, post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like I found the statement where it fails.

I don't understand why but it works when I remove the statements in the return object of dienstleisterRegObjService.js:

```
vorselektiertesProdukt,
regObj,
```

Comment: It's because that isn't valid JS object notation. You are trying to return an object, not an array so it has to contain only key-value pairs.

So you  need to have `{ key: value }` but you just have `{ vorselektiertesProdukt, regObj }` which is just `{ value, value }`

Answer (score 5):

In case someone faces the same issue i Suggest to modify the gulp code to check what the file causes the problem.

go to `node_modules/gulp-uglify/minifier.js`
find the function : `var mangled = trycatch(function () {}`
before return write  `console.log(file.path);`
save the file then try again, you will see the files which is processing

the last file path appears in the terminal before the error is the file which has the error.

Comment: This tells me the output file, in my case vendor.js, but it's not easy to identify which 3rd party component I need to exclude from uglify, or how for that matter.